# Orthographic projection of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, projection

[image]

Rectangle $ABCD$ is projected using orthographic projection onto a plane that makes a known angle with the plane of the rectangle, as shown in the figure above.  Can the lengths of the sides of the rectangle be determined using the projected image?

(Note: This is not specific to the parallelogram given in the figure.)

Comment: In the book "101 Great Problems In Elementary Mathematics" by H. Dorrie, one  proof is that any convex quadrilateral is the perspective image of a square. I d.k. whether perhaps the methods of his proof might be helpful here.

Comment: But in this problem, we are talking about orthographic projection, not perspective projection.

Comment: It is obviously false if the angle is 90 degrees...

Comment: It is not fair to intentionally change a question (after correct answers have already been posted) by editing it in such a way that a posting that answered the original question absolutely correctly now becomes incorrect due to this change of the question.

Comment: OK, appreciate that.

Comment: Quote from https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit (bold highlight by me)): *"Some common reasons to edit are: [...] to clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it**"* -  You did change your question, and this is against the rules.

Comment: Yeah.  Well, I am terribly sorry about that.  There's nothing I can do now.  The bounty has been awarded, and I did give you [+1] on your answer.

Comment: I have rolled back this question to the state it was in when the first answer was posted.  It is unfair to both the answerer and future readers to change a question after it has been answered.  This creates a mess for others to clean up.  If you get an answer and realize that you left out an important hypothesis, post a new question.

Comment: @HosamHajeer I do not know how to be more clear about this:  **do not** roll back this question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No.

An orthographic projection from one plane to another plane can be imagined as squashing one direction by a factor of $\cos\theta.$ Therefore, we can undo an orthographic projection by stretching in one direction by a factor of $\sec\theta.$

[Here's a Desmos graph that shows my counterexample.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ws8hnelldc) The points are $(-0.5,0.5s), (0.5,-0.5s), (-\frac{2-k}{2\sqrt7},\frac{2+k}{2\sqrt7}s),$ and $ (\frac{2-k}{2\sqrt7},-\frac{2+k}{2\sqrt7}s).$ Varying $k$ stretches the four points by a factor of $k$ in the direction of the line $x = y$, and preserving the line $x = -y.$ Varying $s$ stretches along the $y-$axis and preserves the $x-$axis. As can be seen in the graph, stretching along either of those directions by a factor of $\sqrt3$ by changing $k$ or $s$ to $\sqrt3$ makes the given parallelogram into a rectangle. Since we can undo the orthographic projection in two different ways to get a rectangle, the rectangle is not uniquely determined.

(Footnote: The angle $\theta$ in my counterexample is $\arccos \sqrt\frac{1}{3}.$)

Comment: I chose two pairs of opposite points on two ellipses with the same eccentricity and center. Stretching either of them to make a circle would turn the set of four points into a rectangle.

Comment: Updated the link so that we can see which lines the points are being "pulled away" from.

Comment: Your Desmos graph is an incorrect example, because orthogonality of two adjacent sides of the rectangle is not in the plane of the image, but contains the third dimension ($z$) as well.

Comment: Basically, an orthographic projection is squishing, and I showed how it can be undone to provide two different rectangles.

Comment: But it is also a projection, so the $z$ information (perpendicular to the plane of the image) is not showing.

Comment: That is true. The sides of the rectangles are sloped, so the lack of z information is shown as a "squashing" effect, which is undone by the "stretching" example in my Desmos graph.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

This can be shown intuitively with a simple example:

Suppose that the angle is $\frac{\pi}{3}=60°$ (such that the cosine of this angle is $\frac{1}{2}$) and that the projected figure is a rectangle with sides $1$ and $2$.

From the fact that the projected figure is a rectangle, we can conclude that the intersection line of the two planes must be parallel to one of the sides of the rectangle. But we don't know which.

- If it is parallel to the long side, then the original rectangle must be a square with side length $2$.
- If the intersection line is parallel to the short side, then we know that the original rectangle has side lengths of $1$ and $4$.

But we have no way to distinguish between these two cases.

Comment: This is just a duplicate of a special case of my answer.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question "what if the angle can't be 60 degrees?"

Comment: @mathlander: It is a more intuitive answer without formulas and therefore easier to understand. Your answer is the typical complicated answer of a mathematician. My answer is the answer of a teacher. I think my answer is didactically better.

Comment: The OP has 13k rep. He would be able to understand my answer.

Comment: @mathlander: Correct. My answer does not answer a question that was not asked. I gave a counterexample. This counterexample proves that the assumption was wrong. There is nothing more to do here.

Comment: @mathlander: Other people than the OP will also read the answer and vote for them. Why are you posting all your comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141854/discussion-between-mathlander-and-hubert-scholnast).

Comment: Also, I corrected the post by changing "sine" to "cosine".

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Sorry, I don't like chats.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I've modified the question to include that the condition that the given projected image of the rectangle is not a rectangle itself (the text in bold).

Comment: @HosamHajeer: It is totally unfair to change your question **after** I posted my absolutely correct answer, with the sole purpose of making my previously correct answer wrong now.

Comment: I can change my question at any time I want.  It is your responsibility to change your posted answer to adapt to the newly modified question.  And this is what @mathland did, he gave a very good answer that proved that the recovered rectangle is not unique with an example that conforms to the modified conditions in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A rough 3d *Geogebra* sketch of related projection geometry of a rectangular prism.

[image]

A rectangular prism between planes

$$ (\pm 3,\pm4,0), (\pm 3,\pm4,5)$$

when cut by a plane of arbitrary inclination produces a section with  parallelogram boundary.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be determined.

Proof: Assume that the angle is known to be $\theta.$ Take a square with one of its sides parallel to the plane of projection and with side length $\sec(\theta).$ It would project to a $1 \times \sec(\theta)$ rectangle.  A rectangle with the short side parallel to the plane of projection that has dimensions $1 \times \sec^2(\theta)$ also projects to a rectangle which has dimensions $1 \times \sec(\theta)$. Since these two different rectangles project to the same rectangle, it is impossible to tell which one is the square, so they cannot be determined, even if we can choose the angle $\theta.$

Comment: I've modified the question to include that the condition that the given projected image of the rectangle is not a rectangle itself (the text in bold).

Comment: I answered the new version of the question too.